# memory issues when transforming np.array using to_categorical

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, classification

I have a numpy array like this:

```
[[0. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 1.]]
```

I transform it like this to reduce the memory demand:

```
x_val = x_val.astype(np.int)
```

resulting in this:

```
[[0 1 1 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 ... 1 0 1]]
```

However, when I do this:

```
x_val = to_categorical(x_val)
```

I get:

```
in to_categorical
    categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=np.float32)
MemoryError
```

Any ideas why? Ultimately, the numpy array contains the labels for a binary classification problem. So far, I have used it as `float32` as is in a Keras ANN and it worked fine and I achieved pretty good performance. So is it actually necessary to run `to_categorical`?

Comment: If it's a binary classification problem the labels should be zeros and ones; however your labels seems very strange to me! For example, what does the first row, i.e. `[0. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.]`, correspond to when interpreted as a label? If you want to perform binary classification the labels should have a shape of `(n_samples,)`. I guess you are doing multi-label classification, i.e. each sample may have multiple labels. In that case the labels are correct as they are and you don't need to use `to_categorical` at all.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with to_categorical? For me it looks misplaced here.

Comment: @today sorry I may be missing something here but isn't 0. = 0 => Class1 and 1. = 1 > Class2. The latter class is to be predicted ...

Comment: @Digital-Thinking not sure I understand. Is it missplaced as in a multi class problem I would use categorical_crossentropy as loss function whereas in a binary classification problem I use binary_crossentropy (as I currently do)? Hence to_categorical does not make sense her as this is binary?

Comment: How big is your array? How much memory do you have?

Comment: to_categorical does make sense if you have multicalss label, which are stored in one single value. If you have classes like (0,1,2,3,n) they are onehot encoded and you get a dimension per distinct value (n-dimensional array per value).

Comment: @Digital-Thinking ok thanks - so what I am doing is pointless in this scenario still puzzled by the memory issue - there are about 1.3 million rows, which should not be an issue IMHO.

Comment: Probably you can use sparse vectors/matrices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use `to_categorical` since I guess you are doing multi-label classification. To avoid any confusion once and for all(!), let me explain this.

If you are doing **binary classification**, meaning each sample may belong to only one 
of two classes e.g. cat vs dog or happy vs sad or positive review vs negative review, then:

- The labels should be like `[0 1 0 0 1 ... 0]` with shape of `(n_samples,)` i.e. each sample has a one (e.g. cat) or zero (e.g. dog) label.
- The activation function used for the last layer is usually `sigmoid` (or any other function that outputs a value in range [0,1]).
- The loss function usually used is `binary_crossentropy`.

If you are doing **multi-class classification**, meaning each sample may belong to only one of many classes e.g. cat vs dog vs lion or happy vs neutral vs sad or positive review vs neutral review vs negative review, then:

- The labels should be either one-hot encoded, i.e. `[1, 0, 0]` corresponds to cat, `[0, 1, 0]` corresponds to dog and `[0, 0, 1]` corresponds to lion, which in this case the labels have a shape of `(n_samples, n_classes)`; Or they can be integers (i.e. sparse labels), i.e. `1` for cat, `2` for dog and `3` for lion, which in this case the labels have a shape of `(n_samples,)`. The `to_categorical` function is used to convert sparse labels to one-hot encoded labels, of course if you wish to do so.
- The activation function used is usually `softmax`.
- The loss function used depends on the format of labels: if they are one-hot encoded, `categorical_crossentropy` is used and if they are sparse then `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used.

If you are doing **multi-label classification**, meaning each sample may belong to zero, one or more than one classes e.g. an image may contain both cat and dog, then:

- The labels should be like `[[1 0 0 1 ... 0], ..., [0 0 1 0 ... 1]]` with shape of `(n_samples, n_classes)`. For example, a label `[1 1]` means that the corresponding sample belong to both classes (e.g. cat and dog).
- The activation function used is `sigmoid` since presumably each class is independent of another class.
- The loss function used is `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: Amazing summary! Btw when I apply x_val = x_val.astype(np.uint8) to my training labels of my binary classification problem, the AUC on the test data is much lower ... so transforming the labels from float to int causes issues!

Comment: @cs0815 You don't need to convert to int. I guess the issue is caused by the fact that in a neural network you are dealing with float values; even the output of binary classification method is a float value between zero and one which corresponds to the probability of belonging to positive class. Therefore the internal computations like computing loss or gradient may be affected by this conversion. Usually all the values must be float unless it is required otherwise (like the input of an Embedding layer which should be integers).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the application of to_categorical is pointless in my scenario. The following solves the memory issue:

```
x_val = x_val.astype(np.uint8)
```