# keras custom metrics for multi-label classfication

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm using `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` for multi-label classification.

For example, the label of `y_true` is like `[1,0,1,0,0]`, and the label of `y_pred` is like `[0.8,0.3,0.9,0,0]`.

How can I set a Keras custom metric function so that each element in `y_pred` larger than 0.5 is mapped to 1, each element in `y_pred` lower than 0.5 is mapped to 0, then compare the number of labels in `y_pred` that matches the `y_true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing multi-label classification, it seems you want to compare the whole true and predicted labels with each other. For example, for one single sample with a true label of `[1, 0, 0]` and a predicted label of `[0, 0, 0]` you consider the prediction accuracy as zero (despite the fact that the labels for the second and third classes have been predicted correctly). If that's the case, you can compare the labels and then use `all()` method from backend to make sure the labels for all the classes match with each other:

```
from keras import backend as K

def full_multi_label_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    comp = K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred))
    return K.cast(K.all(comp, axis=-1), K.floatx())
```

Comment: As per @today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890883/memory-issues-when-transforming-np-array-using-to-categorical/51892084#51892084