# keras custom metrics for multi-label classification without all()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm using sigmoid and binary_crossentropy for multi-label classification. A very similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037451/keras-custom-metrics-for-multi-label-classfication). And the following custom metric was suggested:

```
from keras import backend as K

def full_multi_label_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    comp = K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred))
    return K.cast(K.all(comp, axis=-1), K.floatx())
```

But I do not want to use all() because for one single sample with a true label of [1, 0, 0, 1, 1] and a predicted label of [0, 0, 0, 1, 1] I do not consider the prediction accuracy as zero (due to the the fact that the labels for the last four classes have been predicted correctly).

Here is my model:

```
# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=-9999, input_shape=(197, 203)))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=SGD(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-4, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Here is my y_pred for one example:

```
pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = pred[0,196,:]
y_pred
array([2.6081860e-01, 9.9079555e-01, 1.4816311e-01, 8.6009043e-01,
       2.6759505e-04, 3.0792636e-01, 2.6738405e-02, 8.5339689e-01,
       5.1105350e-02, 1.5427300e-01, 6.7039116e-05, 1.7909735e-02,
       6.4140558e-04, 3.5133284e-01, 5.3054303e-02, 1.2765944e-01,
       2.9298663e-04, 6.3041472e-01, 5.8620870e-03, 5.9656668e-01],
      dtype=float32)
```

Here is my y_true for one example:

```
y_true = Y_test[0,0,:]
y_true
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 1.])
```

My question is: How can I set a Keras custom metric function so that each element in y_pred should be compared to the each element in y_true, then an accuracy measure will be given during training? I want to use this metric in `metrics = [X])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken the default binary_crossentropy metric/loss already does what you need. Taking your example

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.int32)
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.6, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)

m = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
m.numpy()
```

The output is [-log(0.6) / 5].

i.e. The metric/loss for the batch takes into account the losses for each of the 20 outputs of the model. Which I'm assuming represent time steps.

As a metric, it is much more common to use binary_accuracy.
Example:

```
y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.int32)
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.1, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32), y_pred)
```

One can get a better idea of the performance of the model via an ROC metric (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) which measures the curve at various thresholds see an explanation at https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5. Personally, I tend to use an accuracy metric while training and look at the precision/recall curve after the model is trained in order to check that it behaves as expected and select the prediction threshold.

Comment: @ENESAVCU apologies for misreading the question; binary_crossentropy is typically used as a loss and binary_accuracy as a metric.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What I want is better than something that uses 0.5 as threshold. I think having a threshold is be a pretty coarse measure of accuracy. Suppose the output is 0.51 at all the “on elements” in the correct pattern and 0.49 at all the “off” units. That shouldn’t have the same accuracy as 0.99 at the on units and 0.01 at the off units!

Comment: @ENESAVCU Added information regarding AUC metric.

Comment: I tried AUC during training. It has nice arguments like multi_label=False and num_labels=None. I set the multi_label=True, num_labels=20. But when I try to model.fit, this gives error and complain about the input dimension, my input dimension is 3 (example, time, channel), but it says the dimension should be 2!

Comment: You can create a wrapper that reshapes the tensor to (batch_size, -1). But imho loss / val_loss already does a good job of tracking how far the value is from a 0, 1 label.