# Shape error when training a model with Keras (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am newbie to machine learning and finding tough to grasp training of model using Keras for TensorFlow. I am trying time series prediction using TensorFlow. I have a generator function which generates the training data and labels:

```
x_batch, y_batch = next(generator)

print(x_batch.shape)
print(y_batch.shape)

(256, 60, 9)
(256, 60, 3)
```

I build the model in the following way:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, num_x_signals,), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(num_y_signals, activation='relu'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

My model summary looks like below:

```
    model.summary()
  _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, None, 128)         70656     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_23 (Dropout)         (None, None, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (Batc (None, None, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_20 (LSTM)               (None, None, 128)         131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_24 (Dropout)         (None, None, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (Batc (None, None, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_21 (LSTM)               (None, 128)               131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_25 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_20 (Batc (None, 128)               512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 32)                4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_26 (Dropout)         (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 99        
=================================================================
Total params: 339,587
Trainable params: 338,819
Non-trainable params: 768
```

This is how I try to train the model:

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}"  # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones

# Train model
history = model.fit_generator(
    generator=generator,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=100,      
    validation_data=validation_data,
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)

# Score model
score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
# Save model
model.save("models/{}".format(NAME))
```

But I am getting the below error when I try to train my model:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-f5263636596b> in <module>()
     10     steps_per_epoch=100,
     11     validation_data=validation_data,
---> 12     callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
     13 )
     14 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1777         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1778         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1779         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1780 
   1781   def evaluate_generator(self,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    134             'or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: ' + str(validation_data))
    135       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weights = model._standardize_user_data(
--> 136           val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)
    137       val_data = val_x + val_y + val_sample_weights
    138       if model.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    915           feed_output_shapes,
    916           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 917           exception_prefix='target')
    918 
    919       # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    180                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    181                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 182                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    183         if not check_batch_axis:
    184           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 219, 3)
```

Comment: What's the shape of your input validation data?

Comment: Because you stop using `return_sequences=True` at some point, your network goes from 2D to 1D. But your `y` data is in 2D, hence the error you are getting.

Comment: @IanQuah, My validation looks like this - X is (1, 219, 9) and Y is (1, 219, 3). And by build validation data like validation_data = (np.expand_dims(x_test_scaled, axis=0),
                   np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0)).... So essentially I enduo with a tupple of arrays of dimensions (1, 219, 9) and (1, 219, 3)

Comment: @yhenon, I construct data using expand_dims, like I said above. so essentially my Y is 3D

Comment: @yhenon, I tried to pass in return_sequences=True all the time, and this time I get the below error.  expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (219, 3). I dont understand Why (None, 1) is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yhenon mentioned in the comments section since your model has some outputs for each timestep, you must use `return_sequences=True` for the last LSTM layer as well.

However, it is not clear what the task is (i.e. classification or regression). If it is a classification task you must use `'categorical_crossentropy'` as the loss function (instead of `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` which you are currently using) and use `'softmax'` as the activation function of last layer.

On the other hand, if it is a regression task you need to use a regression loss such as `'mse'` or `'mae'` and set the activation function of last layer properly, depending on the output values (i.e. use `'linear'` if the range of output values include both negative and positive numbers).

Comment: Thanks @Today, Got it, I am doing regression and was using the loss as "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" which I believe resulted in expecting  (None, 1) and when I change this to mse. Everything worked fine. Do you know of any guide I can use to learn more about building models and what layers and activation functions to use?

Comment: @ChiduMurthy Well, there are tons of great articles on the web about machine learning and Keras. If you are looking for some model examples in Keras, you can find great ones in [Keras repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/examples). If you are looking for a succinct and quick guide about loss and activation functions used in classification, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892084/2099607) (Disclaimer: it is written by me!).

Comment: How about regression?

Comment: @ChiduMurthy Well, regression is much more straight forward. Most often for the **common** regression tasks, the loss function used is mean square error or `'mse'` and the activation function is `'linear'` (i.e. no activation). Of course, there are other (special) cases, which depending on the problem and the output values, for example you might use `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` as the activation and loss functions, respectively.