# Bad accuracy when prediction happens

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

After I trained my model for the toxic challenge at Keras the accuracy of the prediction is bad. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but the accuracy during the training period was pretty good ~0.98.

**How I trained**

```
import sys, os, re, csv, codecs, numpy as np, pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, GlobalMaxPool1D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints, optimizers, layers

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')


list_classes = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]
y = train[list_classes].values
list_sentences_train = train["comment_text"]

max_features = 20000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(list_sentences_train))
list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_sentences_train)

maxlen = 200
X_t = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)

inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))

embed_size = 128
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size)(inp)
x = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True,name='lstm_layer')(x)
x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(50, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
print(X_t[0])
model.fit(X_t,y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

model.save("m.hdf5")
```

**This is how I predict**

```
model = load_model('m.hdf5')

list_sentences_train = np.array(["I love you Stackoverflow"])

max_features = 20000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(list_sentences_train))
list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_sentences_train)

maxlen = 200
X_t = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)

print(X_t)

print(model.predict(X_t))
```

**Output**

> [[  1.97086316e-02   9.36032447e-05   3.93966911e-03   5.16672269e-04
>       3.67353857e-03   1.28102733e-03]]

Comment: Can a single sample have multiple labels (i.e. is it a multi-label classification task?), for example both "toxic" and "threat"?

Comment: No not really @today

Comment: Then you should not use `sigmoid` as the activation function of last layer and `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function. Instead use `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892084/2099607).

Comment: Thanks, but its still strange. Always getting values around this [[ 0.68699586  0.00641587  0.13240167  0.00581519  0.15096234  0.01740919]] @today

Comment: And what's strange about that exactly? Did you mean for **totally different** samples you get the **same prediction**?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the input is. The output is always around these example values. This is btw where I have the code from https://www.kaggle.com/sbongo/for-beginners-tackling-toxic-using-keras/data @today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193948/discussion-between-bilalreffas-and-today).

Comment: Oh, good that you provided the link to the original problem. This is a multi-label problem per the definition provided in the challenge. And therefore, your original solution is correct. And also there is no problem with the prediction you get for the `I love you Stackoverflow` input with your original model: since all the values (i.e. probabilities) are near zero, then it means none of the labels are present in the given input, which is absolutely expected and correct.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but changing it to "I will kill you" give me following result [[  1.24361124e-02   1.38680343e-05   1.83900306e-03   1.23052538e-04
    1.84579729e-03   6.02254237e-04]]. So not understanding what I'm doing wrong @today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In inference (i.e. prediction) phase, you should use the **same pre-processing steps** you have used during training of the model. Therefore, you should not create a new `Tokenizer` instance and fit it on your test data. Rather, if you want to be able to do prediction later with the same model, besides the model you must also save all the statistics you obtained from the **training data** like the vocabulary in `Tokenizer` instance. Therefore it would be like this:

```
import pickle

# building and training of the model as you have done ...

# store all the data we need later: model and tokenizer    
model.save("m.hdf5")
with open('tokenizer.pkl', 'wb') as handler:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handler)
```

And now in prediction phase:

```
import pickle

model = load_model('m.hdf5')
with open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handler:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handler)

list_sentences_train = ["I love you Stackoverflow"]

# use the the same tokenizer instance you used in training phase
list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_sentences_train)
maxlen = 200
X_t = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)

print(model.predict(X_t))
```

Comment: Is the method correct? TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I assume "wb" is missing.

Comment: @BilalReffas That's right. Fixed it. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Mhh should i need to cast it somehow ? AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'texts_to_sequneces'

Comment: @BilalReffas Sorry, I did not test my codes. I have misspelled `sequences` as `sequneces`. Fixed that as well.

Comment: **Facepalm** Thank you so much! For helping. You need to change r to rb at the prediction phase though.

Comment: @BilalReffas Oh, I missed that as well. This happens when one writes code in a hurry and also does not test it! Sorry!

Comment: Any ideas how to get the prediction working via Tensorflowjs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333294/converting-python-keras-nlp-model-to-tensorflowjs