# Converting Python Keras NLP Model to Tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflowjs-converter, tensorflowjs

I'm trying to learn more about Tensorflowjs, but sadly I'm stuck getting my Keras NLP Model converted to Tensorflowjs.

This is what I'm trying to convert:

```
from keras.models import load_model

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

import pickle

list_classes = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

model = load_model('Keras_Model/m.hdf5')
with open('Keras_Model/tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handler:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handler)

list_sentences_train = ["I need help Stackoverflow"]

list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(list_sentences_train)
maxlen = 200
X_t = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)


pred = model.predict(X_t)[0]
```

Tensorflowjs side:

```
import tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

async function processModel(){
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('Server_Model/model.json');
}
```

How I can get the Tokenizer running and make correct predictions?

Comment: Do you want to run the Tokenizer some how in JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah I want that @ShubhamPanchal

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I ran into the same problem while classifying text on Android. I had the model ( tflite ) ready to use, but how can I tokenize the sentences just as Keras did in Python.

I found a simple solution which I have discussed [here](https://link.medium.com/SaBG73mXZW) ( for Android ).

> The simple idea is to convert the `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`
>   vocabulary to a JSON file. This JSON file could be parsed in any of
>   the programming languages including JavaScript.

The Tokenizer holds a object called `word_index`.

```
index = tokenizer.word_index
```

The word_index object is a dict which can be converted to JSON like,

```
import json 
with open( 'word_dict.json' , 'w' ) as file:    
    json.dump( tokenizer.word_index , file )
```

The JSON file contains pairs of words and indexes. You can parse it in JavaScript as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935684/10878733).