# Image classification using Keras for 3 classes return only one value instead of 1 X 3 array

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am training a Keras model for multi-label image classification, i.e. 3 classes namely flood, wildfire, storm.

But I am getting only `[[1.]]` instead of something like `[0 0 1]`. So if third bit is one, its a storm. But I don't know why it's returning just a single value `[[1.]]`.

```
# # Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
def create_model() :
    # Initialising the CNN
    classifier = Sequential()
    # Step 1 - Convolution
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    # Step 2 - Pooling
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    # Adding a second convolutional layer
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    # Step 3 - Flattening
    classifier.add(Flatten())
    # Step 4 - Full connection
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    return classifier

def train_save_model():
    classifier = create_model()
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    # Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
    target_size = (64, 64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary')
    test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('validation_set',
    target_size = (64, 64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary')
    classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
    steps_per_epoch = 1407,
    epochs = 1,
    validation_data = test_set,
    validation_steps = 100)

    classifier.save_weights("model.h5")

# Part 3 - Making new predictions
def test_model():
    classifier = create_model()
    classifier.load_weights("model.h5")
    test_image = image.load_img('validation_set/tornado/110.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    # print(test_image)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    )
    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
    target_size = (64, 64),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'binary')
    training_set.class_indices
    # print(training_set.class_indices)
    print(result)

train_save_model()
test_model()
```

> `result = classifier.predict(test_image)`

I tried printing this `result` variable and I get `[[1.]]`. I cannot understand at all how's that happening.

Answer (score 3):

If you have N labels, then the last layer (i.e. the sigmoid classifier layer) must also have N neurons, one for each of the classes:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Then the output of the model, for each input sample, would be 3 numbers corresponding to three labels.

**Update:** Remove the `class_mode = 'binary'` from all `flow_from_directory` calls. That's because you are doing classification among multiple classes and therefore the generated labels should be either categorical (default behavior) or sparse (i.e. `class_mode='sparse'`). Further, after reading the relevant parts of your code, it seems that you are doing **multi-class** classification, and not **multi-label** classification. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892084/2099607) to make sure and also to find out which activation and loss function you should use.

Comment: Thanks for answering :). However after doing that change, I am running into an error.                     ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Also now i have 5 Classes, therefore it says expected to have shape (5,)

Comment: Could you please help, I think there is a problem in the create_model() function?

Comment: @CajetanRodrigues I just updated my answer. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As **loss** function use *categorical_crossentropy* instead of *binary_crossentropy*.